# Creating health bar that increases in value based on users level

Tags: javascript, css

Hello I am trying to create a healthbar that scales in max value based on the users level.

But I am kinda stuck with it because everytime the healthbar ends up in not having the right length based on the users level and it's health. The system works like this: the user starts at level 1 with a health value of 150 and increases + 10 everytime the user levels up, the max level that exists is 32.

Now I know this might be possible to do with a loop but I am not sure on how do this correctly:

This is the code for the health bar.  The user_level is the users level and I am trying to change the element style based on his health, but at the same time that it would match with the current level of the user.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < user_level.value; i++) {
playerhealthbar.style.width = user_health // Something here but I dont know how to.
}
```

This is the CSS code if it helps. What happens is that the greenbar should shrink so that the red bar underneath becomes visible.

```css
#playerhealth {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
height: 45px;
width: 325px;
background: lightgreen;
}

#playerhealthbar {
position: absolute;
height: 50px;
width: 330px;
border: rgb(255, 255, 255) 3px solid;
border-radius: 3px;
margin-right: 20px;
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 442px;
margin-left: 70px;
background: rgb(158, 31, 31);
}


#playerhealthvalue{
position: absolute;
margin-top: 500px;
margin-left: 220px;
font-size: 30px;
color: black;
}
```

Comment: It is not really clear what you mean with `Hello I am trying to create a healthbar that scales in max value based on the users level.` Does the dimension of the healthbar change when the level increases? If how should the width map to the maxhealth? Or does the size stay the same but the current health has to scale differently based on the max health?

Comment: A css width requires a unit, eg px or %. Use your browser dev tools inspect facility to see what value is, or isn’t, being set.

Comment: @t.niese It's kinda hard for me to explain but ill give it a try:  The complete outerbar stays the same. But the greenbar thats inside the whole frame shrinks in size when the health goes down. So I would say that it should take longer for the greenbar to shrink down in size if the health gets higher if that makes any sense. If you want to know more please let me know.

Comment: But it also has to take in to account that the max health increases with every level by +10

Comment: Is it possible for you to use `CSS custom properties` in your project?

Comment: @t.niese Uhm yeah sure

Comment: @t.niese But even if I would use that then I still don't know on how to loop trough correctly and take in to account that the health scales with +10 every level.

Comment: What kind of "looping" are you even talking about here? Where does this need a loop - when you can simply _do the Math_ ...? _"the user starts at level 1 with a health value of 150 and increases + 10 everytime the user levels up, the max level that exists is 32."_ - so the user's current health value will always be `150 + (current_level minus 1) * 10` (or 140 + current_level * 10, if you like that better.)

Comment: @SpringerJerry `I wont even read you're answer since you seem like a all knowing god programmer with all the knowledge of the world.`  I don't think the comment of CBroe is toxic. Yes it could be worded differently, but the same is true for your comment.

Comment: @t.niese Thats fine you don't have to agree with me. But if you respond like that then don't be suprised if some one might respond back at you like that. I am trying to learn something here. And not for beign told that I should have known better.

Comment: @SpringerJerry Yes, but you complain about such comments making this place toxic and at the same time write that in a way that can also be considered as being toxic. If you want to change something and be better, then complain about it without writing it in a toxic way.

Comment: @t.niese Yes you have a point I could have ignored it you are right. Sometimes I just get to triggerd by people when I am just trying  looking for help. Next time Ill just flag a comment if I think that its unappropiate instead of commenting on it.

Comment: @SpringerJerry No, I didn't say to ignore it. That's doesn't help either. But complain about it in an objective way.  Then you at least have the chance that the person thinks about if the wording might have been chosen differently and might consider that for future posts. If you reply with something the other person might see as an attack then you are more likely to achieve the opposite. And you should always also keep in mind that there might be a misunderstanding due to language barriers.

Comment: What exactly is triggering you here? _"when I am just trying looking for help"_ - did I not offer exactly that? I pointed out that you are overcomplicating things by thinking about using any loops (is the mere fact I did that, what's gotten you so enraged here?), and offered you a way simpler approach. The _only_ comment I see worth of flagging for being inappropriate here so far, is _your_ reaction that you gave me.

Comment: @CBroe this will be my last reply. What kind of "looping" are you even talking about here? Where does this need a loop - when you can simply do the Math ...? How do you think that this sounds? Do you think its adding anything to this question?

Comment: @CBroe To be fair `where does this need a loop - when you can simply do the Math ...?`  can sound _"arrogant"_ (not toxic), but I'm neither a native English speaker nor do I really care about these small details here on SO, because there can always be language barriers. As long as it is not fully clear to me that it is meant as a toxic comment (which it is in most cases) I always assume that there is a misunderstanding. Especially when the comment provides additional information about how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The complete outerbar stays the same. But the greenbar thats inside the whole frame shrinks in size when the health goes down.

So the first thing you have to calculate is what the current maximum health value is. This is given by `currentMaxHealth = 150 + 10 * (level-1)`.

The percent of the green bar is `playerHealth / currentMaxHealth * 100`.

The whole logic can be done with just custom properties `calc` and `var`.

So the CSS could look like this:

```js
function setCurrentHealth(val) {
  let root = document.documentElement;
  root.style.setProperty('--curr-health', val);
}

function setUserLevel(level) {
  let root = document.documentElement;
  root.style.setProperty('--user-level', level);
}

document.querySelector('#level').addEventListener('input', (evt) => {
  setUserLevel(evt.target.value)
})

document.querySelector('#health').addEventListener('input', (evt) => {
  setCurrentHealth(evt.target.value)
})
```

```css
:root {
  --user-level: 1;
  --curr-health: 10;
  --base-health-level: 150;
  --additional-health-per-level: 10;
}

.current-health {
  width: calc(var(--curr-health) / (var(--base-health-level) + var(--additional-health-per-level) * (var(--user-level) - 1)) * 100%);
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.health-bar {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="health-bar">
  <div class="current-health">
  </div>
</div>

Level:  <input value="1" id="level"><br>
Health: <input value="10" id="health">
```